# Having trouble rewriting CSS as Sass - nesting and selector combinations

Tags: css, sass

I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to write the CSS as SASS. I have tried nesting the code and using the & sign to combine the selectors, but I don't know what I'm doing.

This is the code that I am trying to rewrite as SASS

```
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul, li {
list-style-type: none;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-weight: none;
}

// general

body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.app {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 5fr;
}

// renders the element off screen so that
// screen readers can still read the text.

.offscreen {
position: absolute;
left: -1000px;
}

// Navigation

.primary-list {
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: #000;
height: 100vh;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
padding-left: 2rem;
}

.primary-list__item {
padding: .5rem;
}

.primary-list__link {
letter-spacing: .05rem;
color: #888;
}

.primary-list__link--active,
.primary-list__link:hover {
color: #FFF;
}

// mail list

.secondary-list {
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.secondary-list__item {
padding: 2rem;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
color: #999;
}

.secondary-list__item--active,
.secondary-list__item:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px #DDD;
}

.secondary-list__row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.secondary-list__title {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}

.secondary-list__aside {
font-style: italic;
}

// mail content

.content {
padding: 2rem;
}

.content__title {
font-size: 4rem;
width: 70%;
margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.content p {
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
line-height: 2rem;
}
```

I would like to see what this code would look like written as SASS also known as SCSS

Comment: I already see some errors. But I'm wondering what error messages you get ;) please edit your question, adding those error messages.

Comment: https://css2sass.herokuapp.com

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I would recommend reviewing documentation for SASS as you've not shown us any SCSS that you've written. I would also refer you to this excellent article from CSS-Tricks on using SASS in conjunction with BEM: https://css-tricks.com/using-sass-control-scope-bem-naming/

Comment: `"SASS also known as SCSS"`. Sass is the preprocessor name while SCSS is one of the two available extensions.

Comment: @QuentinVeron Scss is a newer *version* of Sass that utilizes a different file extension. They're both "Sass".

Comment: @TylerH I know, I was quoting the post owner.

Comment: @QuentinVeron I was correcting the non-quote part of your comment. The post owner was not wrong.

Comment: @TylerH Nothing's wrong with the non-quote part of my comment. My english might not be perfect, far from there, but you basically just repeated my comment. "Sass is the preprocessor name which owns two file extensions: `.sass` and `.scss`. Both have different syntax."

Comment: @QuentinVeron No, I am saying that both terms, Sass and Scss, are used to refer to the pre-processor known as Sass. They are not used in common parlance to refer *exclusively* to the file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is all you need to do is change the CSS extension to SCSS and compile it (**any valid CSS is also valid SCSS**).

The long answer is you can do this in a lot of ways – I prefer mixins for everything to control rendering order. If you are just starting out I would recommend you to start by looking into nesting, the '&' (the parent selector) and variables (here is a place to start https://sass-lang.com/guide and here https://sass-lang.com/documentation).

Maybe something like this:

```
//  Variables
$color-white: #fff;
$color-black: #000;
$color-gray : #ccc;
$color-light-gray : #ddd;
$color-semi-dark-gray  : #999;
$color-dark-gray  : #888;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: none;
}

// general

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.app {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 5fr;
}

// renders the element off screen so that
// screen readers can still read the text.

.offscreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
}

// Navigation

.primary-list {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: $color-black;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;

    //  Nesting 
    //  .primary-list__item
    &__item {
        padding: .5rem;
    }

    //  .primary-list__link
    &__link {
        letter-spacing: .05rem;
        color: $color-dark-gray;

        //  .primary-list__link--active,
        //  .primary-list__link:hover
        &--active,
        &:hover {
            color: $color-white;
        }
    }
}

// mail list

.secondary-list {
    border-right: 1px solid $color-gray;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;


    //  .secondary-list__item
    &__item {
        padding: 2rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $color-gray;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        color: $color-semi-dark-gray;
    }

    //  .secondary-list--active, 
    //  .secondary-list:hover  
    &--active,
    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px $color-light-gray;
    }

    //  .secondary-list__row
    &__row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    //  .secondary-list__title
    &__title {
        color: $color-black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    //  .secondary-list__aside
    &__aside {
        font-style: italic;
    }
}

// mail content

.content {
    padding: 2rem;

    //  .content__title
    &__title {
        font-size: 4rem;
        width: 70%;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personal opinion, but nesting should not be used like `element > element`. It should be used for **pseudo elements, pseudo classes and combined selectors**. Nothing more.

Comment: I don't disagree and I don't like BEM either ;-)... My answer is an attempt to reflect what I think the teacher is looking for (based on the CSS provided).